# How do I create a Database using C# in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a database in my program but I keep running into host errors or connection errors. Am I missing something I have a table called employee now I just need to populate it with names, ID, etc.

I have my EmployeeListForm for which I used the DatagridView and have titles EmployeeID, last name, firstname, dept, hire date, exempt, budget, salary openings, reportees. Now I want to populate these with data for just five people. I tried the add Item > select data> Local database> but i keep getting errors and it tells me it does not exists.

Here is the exact error message:

```
SQL Server Compact does not support opening database files on a network share. 
Parameter name //vmware-host/sharedFolders.
```

So I am a little confused here. Please Advice

Comment: First and foremost, "i keep getting errors" is never as useful as quoting what the errors actually were.  Second, and I mean this with kindness, please try to read your question as though you were a stranger reading it.  I don't think you'd find it comprehensible.  You need to provide a *lot* more context.

Comment: Kirk, Sorry about that but I just posted the exact error message I am getting. something related to SQL Server compact does not support opening database files on a network share. Parameter anem //vmware-host/sharedFolders.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Compact 3.5 does not support opening database files on a network share.

Source [How to: Create a Database (Devices)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180732(VS.90).aspx)

Translation: It expects the database files to be local.